# Bootstrap 3 tooltips lose styling in modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

I'm using Bootstrap 3 tooltips for a btn-group, and use the same btn-group (which is a partial) in  a modal. However, in the modal, the btn-group tooltips do not inherit the styling they have when not inside a modal.

```
<button id="status-change" v="needs review" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"                title="Needs    Review" class='btn btn-default photo-tool-tip'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span>
</button>
```

Side note, the modal is in HAML with this javascript tag:
  - content_for :javascript do
    $('.photo-tool-tip').tooltip();

Is there something I'm not including the button tag, or possibly more specific because i'm working in a modal?

Comment: There's a typo in the button tag.  Missing end quote on class attribute.  Is it really like that or just in this post?

Comment: @steakchaser - Good eye, but sorry to tell you it's just like this in the post. I had to omit some code, but what was taken out only involved a conditional active class for something unrelated.

Comment: What do the tooltips look like and what does the browser show as the css props?

Comment: The tips are all **data-placement="top"** (seen in working fashion on the Bootstrap site) and when inspect the button the only css styling it has is the color.

When I hover over the buttons, a really archaic version of tooltips pops up below it, and no new div class is inherited. In a working version you can see the new div class (which is actually the tooltip itself) get added when hovering.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://www.bootply.com/kaAUHnc0C4. Unless there's something I missed in your question...

Comment: @ShawnTaylor the solution wound up being - adding .tooltip() in the coffee script. Thanks for looking into it though!